# Class 'collective\Html\FormFacade' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

this is my blade file in laravel.

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store')) !!}

    {{Form::lable('title','Title:')}}

    {{Form::text('title',null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

    {{Form::lable('body',"Post Body:")}}

    {{Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

    {{Form::submit('Create Post', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;'))}}

   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

but when I try to visit this blade file following error is comming

```
Class 'collective\Html\FormFacade' not found
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: yes I did it well

Answer (score 4):

Run this command in composer
`composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"`

Then add your new provider to the `providers` array of `config/app.php` file

`Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`

Finally add two class aliases to the `aliase`s array of `config/app.php` file

`'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`

Ref. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Comment: now got this error class Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider not found in my terminal

Comment: Sounds like `laravelcollective` is not installed properly. check if _composer.jason_ file contains `illuminate/html`. If it it run run `composer update`

Comment: Could not parse version constraint :5.2.0: Invalid version string ":5.2.0"

Comment: In new Laravel version, you can simply run `composer require laravelcollective/html` and you are good to go. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html